# Emulate Windows key on Windows 10 touch keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, tablet

I have a new tablet PC with Windows 10 which doesn't have a physical keyboard. This is OK for most applications, the on-screen keyboard works fine for most uses. However, one of the primary applications for me is to play videos over an external monitor/projector via HDMI, and for that I've found one relevant shortcoming:

The on-screen keyboard doesn't have a Windows key, which I'd need to quickly send a window to the external monitor (Windows+Shift+Right Arrow) and/or put it in full-screen mode (Windows+Up Arrow).

And all the other shortcuts (Windows+I, Windows+X etc.etc.) would be nice to have as well. Is there any way to get them (or an alternate way to simulate them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the keyboard icon (on the bottom-right corner of the taskbar keyboard) to change style of keyboard to the fuller one.

If, like me, you could not access any different "style of keyboard", that's because you need to go to Settings, search Typing, and turn on "Add the standard keyboard layout..".

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of where the OP might find this?

Comment: @Burgi .. Hi, I have since found someone else who said the same thing with screenshots -- see top answer in http://superuser.com/questions/1001053/windows-10-tablet-onscreen-keyboard-arrows?rq=1  :-)

Comment: @user1863152 - In the future instead of submitting a new naswer, that repeats an existing answer of much better quality, you should flag the question as a duplicate of the question with the existing answer.  Worth pointing out, this ended up happening, because of your comment to Burgi.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to long press the windows button on the bottom left corner to bring up the Windows + X menu.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Windows 8.1; is it just a Windows 10 thing?